# How to print the result of a subprocess.call to a file in a python script

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command, jira

I have a python script where I call the JIRA API and getting something from JIRA, which I want to write out to file.

This command in cmd works fine

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X GET --data @file.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:URL >> output.json
```

However, when I try to do the same in Python, it is not writing to my file (goes right to my "something is wrong")

```
#Runs curl script to get component
def write():
    name = 'output.json'

try:
    file= open(name, 'w')
    file.write(subprocess.call('curl -D- -u username:password -X GET --data @file.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:URL'))
    file.close()

except:
    print('something is wrong')
    sys.exit(0)
write()
```

I also tried to just have it write the contents of a variable, below.

```
curler = (subprocess.call('curl -D- -u username:password -X GET --data @file.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:URL'))

def write():
    name = 'output.json'

try:
    file = open(name, 'w')
    file.write(curler)
    file.close()

except:
    print('something is wrong')
    sys.exit(0)
write()
```

I am using Windows 7 and Python 3

Comment: Do you really need to do a shell command, you could use `pycurl` or `requests` to make the call directly in python without shelling out, making it much easier to deal with the returned data.

Comment: Could you show us the Traceback so we can see the actual error?

Comment: See [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: I am going to try and use 'requests' and if I can make anything happen, I'll post back here. Currently im trying to figure out how to pass requests exactly like I want in my CURL command. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` takes a list of arguments and just returns the exit status of the process called. I think you are trying to redirect the standard output to a file:

```
curl = ['curl', '-D-', '-u', 'username:password', '-X', 'GET', '--data',
        '@file.json', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'http:URL']
with open('output.json', 'w') as file:
    status = subprocess.call(curl, stdout=file)
```

Comment: I am changing routes (using requests) but this does seem like the correct solution to my issue so I will make as such. Thank you!

Comment: Windows `CreateProcess` takes a command-line string, not a POSIX-style argument list or array of arguments. The only reason to pass a list on Windows is for cross-platform compatibility and to let `Popen` quote the command per VC++ parsing rules. In this case the command was already properly quoted, e.g.: `subprocess.list2cmdline(curl) ==` `'curl -D- -u username:password -X GET --data @file.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:URL'`. All that was needed was passing `stdout=file` to redirect its standard output.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I don't have a windows machine to test on. Though I would tend to favour portability, so would still use the list on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

1- The reason you're getting an exception is because the way you pass arguments to subprocess. You should give subprocess a list of args and not a single string. Say you want to download google.com using curl:

```
subprocess.call(['curl', 'google.com'])
```

2- subprocess.call returns the exit code, not the output. To redirect the output to a file:

```
subprocess.call(['curl', 'google.com'], stdout=open('myFileName', 'w'))
```